# Generate Unique Random Number

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I know similar questions have been asked, but I have a rather different scenario here.

I have a SQL Server database which will store TicketNumber and other details. This TicketNumber is generated randomly from a C# program, which is passed to the database and stored there. The TicketNumber must be unique, and can be from 000000000-999999999.

Currently, what I do is: I will do a select statement to query all existing TicketNumber from the database:

```
Select TicketNumber from SomeTable
```

After that, I will load all the TicketNumber into a `List`:

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>();
//foreach loop to add all numbers to the List
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 1000000000);
if !(temp.Contain(randomNumber))
//Add this new number to the database
```

There is no problem with the code above, however, when the dataset get larger, the performance is deteriorating. (I have close to hundred thousand of records now). I'm wondering if there is any more effective way of handling this?

I can do this from either the C# application or the SQL Server side.

Comment: How big is the database likely to get, and why does the ticket number need to be random rather than just unique?

Comment: Why don't use Guid or Identity or Sequence ?

Comment: In addition to the performance degradation, as the dataset grows, the probability of a collision increases...can you consider using a sequential ticket number?

Comment: @JonSkeet The actual data that goes into this table is around 1000/day. Also, I have no idea why the business users want it to be randomly generated.

Comment: A hashtable would help, but I agree with everyone above.

Comment: All: Like I said, I cannot. It is not up to me to decide how the systems work.

Comment: I would ask them then - it's entirely possible that it's not really a requirement, and they were just expecting that to be an appropriate approach. Is that range fixed as well, by the way?

Comment: There are times where you just have to do what you're told by your boss.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did ask them. But once again, there is just no way you can talk the client into what you think is better.

Comment: @C.J.: Not if there's a good reason - but if you have "no idea" why the requirement exists, you don't know whether or not there *is* a good reason.

Comment: How about keeping a separate table of unassigned ticket numbers, and deleting them as they are selected? You could even presort the table in a random sequence.

Comment: @C.J. Ask the client exactly why they want it this way when it's clearly problematic and will cause issues later.

Comment: I would use Identity field but if you think you will run out of numbers because you will have bazillion of data... may be you can use guid

Comment: @C.J. Btw, this is a terrible design and is a recipe for trouble; especially over multiple threads.

Comment: @DanHunex you are more likely to run out of disc space than you are to run out of valid values using identity. If you use int you can have a little more than 2 billion rows. If that doesn't do it, switch to bigint. That is probably more than the number of tickets sold worldwide in the last 1,000 years. (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes you can't change the requirements. If you can use a hi/lo scheme to generate unique IDs which aren't random, that would be better.

I assume you've already set this as a primary key in the database. Given that you've already got the information in the database, there's little sense (IMO) in fetching it to the client as well. That goes double if you've got multiple clients (which seems likely - if not now then in the future).

Instead, just *try* to insert a record with a random ID. If it works, great! If not, generate a new random number and try again.

After 1000 days, you'll have a million records, so roughly one in a thousand inserts will fail. That's only one a day - unless you've got some hard limit on the insertion time, that seems pretty reasonable to me.

EDIT: I've just thought of another solution, which would take a bunch of storage, but might be quite reasonable otherwise... create a table with two columns:

```
NaturalID ObfuscatedID
```

Prepopulate that with a billion rows, which you generate by basically shuffling all the possible ticket IDs. It may take quite a while, but it's a one-off cost.

Now, you can use an auto-incrementing ID for your ticket table, and then either copy the corresponding obfuscated ID into the table as you populate it, or join into it when you need the ticket ID.

Comment: I actually think this would be the best solution among the impossible.

Comment: @C.J.: See my alternative at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate table with only one column . Lets just name it UniqueID for now. Populate that column with UniqueID = 000000000-999999999. Everytime you want to generate a random number, do something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 UniqueID From (Table) WHERE UniqueID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM (YOUR TABLE))
```

Code has not been tested but just to show the idea

Comment: @xxbbcc Lock the table then

Comment: So you are saying only one ticket can be generated at a time?

Comment: @C.J. One thread at a time. if one thread tries to generate 10 tickets, feel free to do so